# R DiagrammeR Package - Labels for Path Diagram to be dynamic

Tags: r

I am trying to represent the output of an algorithm at each step, and after some googling found that I could use DiagrammeR package. I am looking at an output like below

[image]

The code for the above is like this -

```
library('DiagrammeR')
grViz("
  digraph boxes_and_circles {

  # a 'graph' statement
  graph [overlap = true, fontsize = 10]

  # several 'node' statements
  node [shape = box,
  fontname = Helvetica]
  A; B; C; D; E; F, G


  # several 'edge' statements
  A->C B->C C->D D->E E->F
  F->G
  }
  ")
```

Only that I want the labels A,B etc to be replaced with the values of certain variables. Is this possible in DiagrammeR ? Else, can some one suggest a different package please. Thanks

Comment: Both the answers below dont work if the label has more than a word :(

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this makes the approach clear, essentially I think you should just dynamically construct your function definition that you pass on to `grViz()`:

```
library(DiagrammeR)

n <- c("Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "D", "E", "F", "G")

##  Construct your node and edge statements dynamically:
nodes <- paste(n, collapse="; ")

##  Insert parts of edge statements dynamically:
edges <- paste0( 
  n[1], "->", n[3], " ",
  n[2], "->", n[3], " ",
  n[3], "->D ",
  "D->E ",
  "E->F ",
  "F->G "
)

##  Plot graph:
grViz(
  paste0(" digraph boxes_and_circles {

    # a 'graph' statement
    graph [overlap = true, fontsize = 10]

    # several 'node' statements
    node [shape = box,
    fontname = Helvetica]
    ", nodes, "
    # several 'edge' statements
    ", edges, "
    }"
  )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The code to make those is just a text string, so there are many ways you could generate the text needed on the fly

```
f <- function(a,b,c,d,e,f,g) {
  gr <- sprintf("
    digraph boxes_and_circles {

                # a 'graph' statement
                graph [overlap = true, fontsize = 10]

                # several 'node' statements
                node [shape = box,
                fontname = Helvetica]
                %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s, %s


                # several 'edge' statements
                %s->%s %s->%s %s->%s %s->%s %s->%s
                %s->%s
      }", a,b,c,d,e,f,g,a,c,b,c,c,d,d,e,e,f,f,g)
  require('DiagrammeR')
  grViz(gr)
}
```

Use it like so

```
do.call(f, as.list(letters[1:7]))
```

[image]

```
f('head1','head2','next','two','three','four','last')
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried this approach and I keep getting syntax errors.

    `a_label <- paste0("Records identified through database searching", "(n=", 
    length(iris$Species), ")")`

    `f(a_label,'head2','next','two','three','four','last')`

Comment: @Patrick seems like it doesn't like the spaces, so you need to put the string in single or double quotes `a_label <- paste0("\"Records identified through database searching", "(n=", length(iris$Species), ")\"")`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using the graph functions (and the `magrittr` package) you can try this:

```
devtools::install_github('rich-iannone/DiagrammeR')
library(DiagrammeR)
library(magrittr)

label_a <- "Alpha"
label_b <- "Bravo"
label_c <- "Charlie"

graph <- create_graph() %>%
set_global_graph_attr("graph", "overlap", "true") %>%
set_global_graph_attr("node", "shape", "box") %>%
set_global_graph_attr("node", "fontname", "Helvetica") %>%
add_node_df(create_nodes(LETTERS[1:7])) %>%
add_edges("A", "C") %>%
add_edges("B", "C") %>%
add_edges("C", "D") %>%
add_edges("D", "E") %>%
add_edges("E", "F") %>%
add_edges("F", "G") %>%
select_nodes("A") %>%
set_node_attr_with_selection("label", label_a) %>%
clear_selection() %>%
select_nodes("B") %>%
set_node_attr_with_selection("label", label_b) %>%
clear_selection() %>%
select_nodes("C") %>%
set_node_attr_with_selection("label", label_c) %>%
clear_selection()

render_graph(graph)
```

That code creates this:

[image: graph-functions-and-magrittr]

You need to install a recent build of DiagrammeR from GitHub (using `devtools::install_github`) as some of these functions are not available in the latest CRAN release.

Comment: Thanks. Will this work if a label contains more than one word ?

Comment: @indi yes it does work with multiple words (I just tested to make sure). You can force a line break with a `\n` in the label text:
    
    `label_a <- "Alpha\nlet us go"`